# Is it okay to merge seperate MCMC chains, using different seed value?

Tags: r, bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian

I'm new to Bayesian analysis. I'm trying to estimate species's abundance.

As I know, when using MCMC sampling, it is recommended to make more than three chains. However, the function I use can make only one chain; I used `hSDM.Nmixture.iCAR()` of `hSDM package` in R. So, I made three different models with three different seed values. Then, I merged the 3 samples and treated them like 'one big sample'.

Here are my questions;

1. Is it okay to merge seperate MCMC chains, using different seed values?
2. Before merging the 3 chains, I checked that each chain was converged visually, and applied
   Geweke diagnostics. Is it right? Do I have to carry out Geweke diagnostics after merging?
3. I'd like to calcuate Rhat for the merged sample. So, I converted the product of the
   `hSDM.Nmixture.iCAR()` function to `ggs()` product using `ggmcmc package`. Thus, I got
   three `ggs()` products including one chain. Is it possible to merge the three `ggs()`
   products, including one chain, into one `ggs()` product, including three chains?

   If merging `ggs()` is impossible, can you recommend some functions or packages to calculate Rhat and credible
   interval for the merged sample?
4. OR... Is it okay to use one chain sample with long iteration? Then, how much long the chain should be?

Comment: Check the linked thread. TL;DR Yes you can, but before doing this it is worth looking at the differences between the chains to diagnose potential problems with the sampling. In a perfect world, all the samples from MCMC would be i.i.d. so the chains would not matter at all. In reality, there is autocorrelation, so it is worth diagnosing how bad it is, etc.

Comment: @Tim Thank you!